# Duda con el valor de retorno de una funcion recursiva de 2 parametros en C++

Tags: c++, funciones, recursión

Tengo una duda sobre el funcionamiento del siguiente programa con una función recursiva. Se le solicita al usuario un valor inicial y un valor final para que el programa imprima la sucesión de números desde el valor inicial hasta el final.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int escribeNumeros(int,int);

int main(){
    int ini,fin;

    cout<<"Escriba el inicio: ";
    cin>>ini; 
    cout<<"Escriba el fin: "; 
    cin>>fin;
    
    for(int i=ini;i<=fin;i++){
        cout<<escribeNumeros(i,fin)<<" ";
    }   
    
    getch();
    return 0;
} 

int escribeNumeros(int ini,int fin){
    if(ini==fin){
        return ini;
    }
    else{
        return escribeNumeros(ini,fin-1);
    }
}
```

Mi duda es respecto a la siguiente linea de código de la función recursiva:

```
return escribeNumeros(ini,fin-1);
```

¿Cuál es el valor retornado por la función cuando es llamada recursivamente y los valores de ini y fin son diferentes (ejemplo ini=2, fin=4), y mas importante **por qué** se retorna ese valor?

Entiendo que cuando ini y fin son iguales la función devolvería el valor de ini a la llamada anterior, pero no tendría que devolver el valor de ini en todas las llamadas de la función? porque no hay ningún factor extra que modifique el valor del retorno, como por ejemplo que la linea de código fuera:

```
return 1 + escribeNumeros(ini,fin-1);
```

Ahí el numero 1 estaría modificando en uno el valor devuelto por la función donde el retorno de las funciones llegando al caso base seria ini, luego 1 + ini y después 1 + (1 + ini).
Pero no logro entender porque el programa funciona con la linea de código que se encuentra en el programa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función recursiva tiene el caso base y otro.

- El caso base devuelve `ini`.
- El otro devuelve `escribeNumeros(ini,fin-1)`.

El segundo caso siempre va a devolver lo mismo que la ejecución anterior. Por lo tanto acabará devolviendo el caso base. Así que no tiene sentido usar recursión si el resultado es siempre el mismo.

---

Te noto confundido. Como que no esperabas que aparezcan todos los números en la consola.

Supongo que olvidaste que hay un `for` que se encarga de imprimirlos:

```
for (int i=ini;i<=fin;i++){
    cout << escribeNumeros(i,fin) << " ";
}
```

Por recursión, en la función `main` debes hacer una sola llamada.

```
escribeNumeros(i, fin);
```

Y para que los números se escriban por recursión, la función se vería así:

```
void escribeNumeros(int ini, int fin){
    if (ini != fin) {
        escribeNumeros(ini, fin-1);
    }
    cout << fin;
}
```

Comment: Si me encontraba algo confundido debido a que me parecía que el programa no tenia mucha lógica en la función recursiva, ya que solo se la pasa mandando el valor de ini como lo mencionas, así que quería averiguar si había algo sobre el retorno de funciones con recursividad que desconociera (como que al restar/sumar 1 en el parámetro, se retornara dicho parámetro). Pero ahora me queda claro que la función recursiva siempre termina enviando el valor ini y el ciclo incrementa de 1 en 1 el valor de ini con el que se llama a la funcion e imprimiendo dicho valor hasta llegar al valor de fin. Gracias.